# adjective + to + verb vs adjective + verb+ing

Tags: adjectives, grammaticality-in-context, infinitive-vs-gerund

I practice to improve my writting skills. I just learned the following:

**after adjective we use** *to + verb*.

For example,

**These students are difficult** *to teach*.

However, I am confused about the following sentences:

**Different types of models will be necessary**, *depending* **on what forecast horizon is most important.**

**Forecasts that need to be produced frequently are**  *better done using* **an automated system than with methods that require careful manual work.**

And
**Once it has been determined what forecasts are required**, *it is then necessary to find or collect* **the data on which the forecasts will be based**

I am Ok with the latter sentence as it follows what I learned. However, what about the former sentences? Why we did not add *to + verb* to after the *adjective*?

Comment: "Depending" is a preposition, so "depending on what forecast horizon is most important" is not a clause but a preposition phrase functioning as a supplementary adjunct. In your second example "better" is not an adjective but an adverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *These students are* [*difficult to teach*].
>
> [2] *Different types of models will be necessary,* [*depending on what*
> *forecast horizon is most important*].
>
> [3] *Forecasts that need to be produced frequently are better* [*done using an*
> *automated system than with methods that require careful manual work*].

In [1] the infinitival clause is, as you say, complement of "difficult".

In [2] "depending" is a preposition, so "depending on what forecast horizon is most important" is not a clause but a preposition phrase functioning as a supplementary adjunct.

In [3] "better" is not an adjective but an adverb, and adverbs can't take infinitival clauses as complement.